# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException Sax parsing

Tags: android, rss, android-asynctask

This class causing me android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException,i know that i have to use asyncTask to make it but i can't figure out how because i am using 1 fragments and this make my application very slow especially when i laod bitmaps, can any one help me please.

```
public class ContainerData {    

static public Context context;

public ContainerData() {

}


public static ArrayList<Feed> getFeeds(String feedurl){
    SAXParserFactory fabrique = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parseur = null;
    ArrayList<Feed> feeds = null;
    try {
        parseur = fabrique.newSAXParser();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(feedurl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    DefaultHandler handler = new ParserXMLHandler();
    try {
        parseur.parse(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), handler);

        feeds = ((ParserXMLHandler) handler).getData();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return feeds;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AsyncTask` make sure `getFeeds` is called inside the `doInBackground(...)` callback

Comment: @user1664332 here's a [nice short example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask).   
Note that what starts the AsyncTask is the method `readWebpage(View view)` marked in the layout xml at `android:onClick="readWebpage"`

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you use a fragment or not, you're still trying to perform Network activity on the main thread.

Create a generic class that extends `AsyncTask` which can perform all your parsing.

```
public class MyTaskHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
   //Could display progress dialog here
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) 
{
   //Implement your parser here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
{
   //Check result, dismiss dialog etc
}
}
```

Then create a new instance of `MyTaskHandler` and run it...

```
MyTaskHandler myTask = new MyTaskHandler();
myTask.execute("http://www.myxmlsite.com/lists.xml");
```

The execute method can take `(String... params)` so you can pass for example a URL,and retrieve it in `doInBackground(String... params)`

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) 
{
   //Implement your parser here
   String urlToParse = params[0];
}
```

Best of luck.